# Why is return used instead of console.log?

Tags: javascript, return, console.log

I'm trying to learn JS from Codecademy. I'm doing [this excercise](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#).

Can someone please tell me why `return` is used instead of `console.log()`?
I don't fully understand how `return` works.

Answer (score 1):

console.log is useful for debugging purposes, but actually can't *accomplish* anything as far as affecting the surrounding code or application.

return is a way of "returning" a value generated by a function to the place it was called from. Think of it as giving a value to that function.

example:

```
 function retFive(){
   return 5;
 }

 var x = 37 + retFive();
console.log(x); //prints out 42
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

A function in code is really no different from a math function. Think about it this way:

`f(x) = x+1`

Which would "return" something based on the input of `x`.

So `f(1) = 2` because `f(1)` returns the value of `1+1`.

Putting that into Javascript:

```
function f(x){
    return x+1;
}
```

allows us to do this:

```
var y = f(1);
```

Now the value of `y` is 2.

Without a return, we wouldn't be able to assign the value to `y`.

`console.log()` really does nothing. It just logs something to the console to view or debug values.

Answer (score 1):

`return` has pretty much the same behavior as it does in other languages.

From the [return MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller. If the expression is omitted, undefined is returned instead.

What this basically means is that when you call a function `foo()` that has a statement like `return 1;` it will have the value of `1` so: `var bar = foo(); // bar = 1`

```
function foo() {
    return 1;
}
var bar = foo(); // bar = 1
```

`console.log()` can be confusing if you're running the program in the console, it prints the value to the console so if our function `foo` from before was `function foo() { console.log(1); }` our `var bar = foo();` would actually set `bar` to `undefined`.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(1);
}
var bar = foo(); // bar = undefined
```

[console.log() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Answer (score 0):

`Return` Is used to return a value from a function.

```
function foo(){
    return 1;
}

console.log(foo()); //1
```

Useful when you have a function that does an operation that needs to return a value, and saves up space so you don't have to use a variable. It's generally just a more professional way of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Without answering about that exercise specifically, the purpose of a `return` statement is to pass information from one function call to another. This information can be anything - an object, a string, a number, and can have any purpose, whether that be to return information about whether the function was successful or not, or to do a calculation and return the answer so another function can use it.

`Console.log()` simply prints out whatever you pass in as a parameter to the console, which can change depending on your context. It doesn't have anything to do with relaying information from one part of your program to another.