# Two dimensional array is not being printed using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is a two dimensional  array, I just need to print it, but when I loop inside of it I get `[object object]` or `undefined`

```
const myarra = function(){
    return [
        [
          { "dayOfMonth" : 1, "dayOfWeek" : "Fri", "event" : "" },
          { "dayOfMonth" : 2, "dayOfWeek" : "Sat", "event" : "" }
        ]
    ];
};
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021847/for-loop-in-multidimensional-javascript-array) may help you

Comment: `console.log(output);` return gives you variables for assignment

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439410/why-is-return-used-instead-of-console-log)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126844/whats-the-difference-between-console-log-and-return-in-javascript)

for explanations on `console.log()` and `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`

```
const myarra = function(){
  return [[{"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"Fri","event":""},
         {"dayOfMonth":2,"dayOfWeek":"Sat","event":""}]];
  };

JSON.stringify(myarra())
```

Comment: how to print it?console.log(JSON.stringify(myarra()) ?

Comment: Yeah, use console.log

Answer (score 1):

This way you can trace each elements in your array.

Also you can use `JSON.stringify(arrayVariable)` method if you just want to print that array using `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayVariable))` this code.

```js
 function myfunction(){
   var array=[[{"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"Fri","event":""},
         {"dayOfMonth":2,"dayOfWeek":"Sat","event":""}]];
    
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     for(var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
    console.log(array[i][j]);
     }
    }
 };
  
  myfunction();
```

Comment: can you tell me how to print it with JSON.stringify(arrayVariable)?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will Convert a JavaScript value into a string and it will output that string in console using `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrrayvariable))`. For more info about JSON.stringify() refer the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Is this is your expected answer?

Answer (score -1):

because it first creates this array and then writes

```
"[[{"dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"Fri","event":""},
     {"dayOfMonth":2,"dayOfWeek":"Sat","event":""}]];"
```